# INSERT INTO unique field

Tags: java, mysql

I'm creating parcel machine program. Every parcel has unique parcelID which is exported to mysql db. The problem is that every time when I run the program, the program is counting parcelID from 0. I'm looking for a solution which will allow me to check the last parcelID in the database and create row after the last one.

Now it looks like this: 1. I'm creating a new row in db (successfully) by java program. 2. I'm closing the program after some time. 3. I run the program again and I can't add another new row because there is error "duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'".

```
public static void post() throws Exception{

    int parcelID = Parcel.generateID();
    int clientMPNumber = Parcel.typeClientNumber();
    int orderPassword = Parcel.generatePass();

    try{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Parcels.Orders (parcelID, clientMPNumber, orderPassword) VALUES ('"+parcelID+"', '"+clientMPNumber+"', '"+orderPassword+"')");

        posted.executeUpdate();
    }
     catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
     }
     finally{
        System.out.println("Insert completed");
     }
}
```

and the method is:

```
public static int generateID(){
     parcelID = parcelID + 1;
     return parcelID;
 }
```

Comment: Btw.: Don't use `prepareStatement()` and string concat the values in your query anyway. Use `prepareStatement()` to build the "prepared statement" (that is a query with "?" as placeholders for your values) and use `setInt` and `setString` to fill these placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

I'd let the database do the heavy lifting for you - Just define the `parcelID` column as `serial` instead of trying to set its value yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Id generation, just create auto_increment column in database table

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) , define your primary key column to auto increment for each insert so your java code doesn't have to manually calculate primary key value each time.

If that is not a possibility, you need to show how you declare & initialize `parcelID`. As of your current code, `parcelID` looks to be a class level field that gets initialized to zero for each run so you always get the same value - `1`. You need to initialize with last value from data base.

Also, implement suggestion as mentioned in comment to your question regarding `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to attent to.

```
    // parcelID should be an INT AUTOINCREMENT primary key.
    try (PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO Parcels.Orders (clientMPNumber, orderPassword) "
            + "VALUES (?, ?)",
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        posted.setString(1, clientMPNumber);
        posted.setString(2, orderPassword);
        posted.executeUpdate();
        try (ResultSet rsKey = posted.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (rsKey.next()) {
                int parcelID = rsKey.getInt(1);
                return parcelID; // Or such
            }try-with-resources
        }
    }
```

The database can deal with automatic numbering best, so that two transactions at the same time do not steal the same "next" number.

You should **close** things like Connection, PreparedStatement and ResultSet. This can best be done using the a bit awkward syntax of **try-with-resources**. That closes automatically even on exception and return.

PreparedStatements should be used with placeholders `?`. This takes care for escaping special characters like `'` in the password. Also prevents **SQL injection**.

Stylistic better use SQLException above Exception. Better maybe even a `throws SQLException`.